# paho MQTT is not responding with docker container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

i am new to docker and making my first application I would be very thankful if someone points to me right direction.

I build the image and when run this image, I get no response from docker run commands. it keeps loading. below is python script:

When I interrupt(ctrl+c)through keyboard it immediately shows outputs(print statement) otherwise it does not perform anything.

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:2.7-slim
WORKDIR /root/
ADD . /root
RUN pip install numpy
COPY app.py app.py
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Docker run command:

```
docker run ImageName
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution of my problem, docker run commands takes -it flag.

```
sudo docker run -it imageName
```

Answer (score 4):

This is probably because python buffers stdout/stdin by default. Edit your docker file to add the `-u` to the python command line:

```
CMD ["python", "-u", "app.py"]
```